# Simplify multiple calls to ActiveRecord #find down to single line/SQL statement

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, arel

I'm having a little brain block when it comes to condensing the use of two `#find` methods in ActiveRecord down to a single statement and SQL query.

I have a Sinatra route where the slug of both a parent and child record are supplied (the parent has many children). Atm I'm first finding the parent with a `#find_by_slug` call and then the child by `#find_by_slug` again on the matched parents association.

This results in two SQL queries that in my mind should be able to be condensed down to one easily... Only I can't work out how that's achieved with ActiveRecord.

Model, route and AR log below. Using ActiveRecord 3.2

### *Edit*

I realised I need to clarify the exact outcome to require (I write this very late in the day). I only require the `Episode` but atm I'm getting the `Show` first in-order to get to the `Episode`. I only require the `Episode` and figured their must be a way to get at that object without adding the extra line and getting the `Show` first.

### Model

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :episodes
end

class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
end
```

### Sinatra route

```
get "/:show_slug/:episode_slug" do
  @show = Show.find_by_slug show_slug
  @episode = @show.episodes.find_by_slug episode_slug

  render_template :"show/show"
end
```

### ActiveRecord logs

```
Show Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `shows`.* FROM `shows` WHERE `shows`.`slug` = 'the-show-slug' LIMIT 1
Episode Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `show_episodes`.* FROM `show_episodes` WHERE `show_episodes`.`show_id` = 1 AND `show_episodes`.`slug` = 'episode-21' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I clarified in the edit. I only require the Episode object and figure there must be a more efficient way of getting at that object than making two SQL queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the `@episode`, you can  maybe do

```
@episode = Episode.joins(:shows).where('shows.slug = ?', show_slug).where('episodes.slug = ?', episode_slug).first
```

If you also need `@show`, you've got to have two queries.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this doesn't take the `episode_slug` into account so I'll just get the first episode from all of the shows against a show?

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry. Need to add another `.where`. I've changed the answer.